# Plotting in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to plot of $0<x^2 -y^2 \leq 1$ in Mathematica. Previously , I  draw it in Wolfarm Alpha.

[image]

But I want to do it in Mathematica.

I attempted...`Plot2D[0< x^2 - y^2<=1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, -5}]`

How to do it properly? Please help me.

Comment: Try `RegionPlot`

Comment: @LukasLang I have written RegionPlot[0< x^2 - y^2<=1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, -5}]. But it shows nothing.

Comment: You should have observed the error message `RegionPlot::plld: Endpoints for y in {y,-5,-5} must have distinct machine-precision numerical values.` which clearly indicates your mistake.

Comment: Generic plotting reference: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionVisualization.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Contours -> {0, 1}, 
 ContourShading -> {None, Brown, None}]
```

[image]

Or

```
RegionPlot[0 < x^2 - y^2 <= 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

Comment: Thanks. It works.